# Normalization question regarding address,city,country data

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, normalization, denormalization

I currently have 3 tables storing information about all the main cities in the world, each region/state that corresponds to those countries, and each city that is in those states/regions.

[image: City, States and Countries]

Now I have about 6 other tables in my database e.g. the Users or Organisations tables which need the exact same 5 columns: address, suburb, city, state/region, country. So I was wondering if it was 'good' normalization practice to perhaps use a 'Location' table which stores those 5 pieces of information, then the Users or Organisations table would have a location_id to reference back to.

[image: Cities, States and Countries with Location table]

Good idea or bad idea? I'm also considering using a 'Contacts' table in the same principle which would contain home_phone, business_phone, mobile_phone, email_address rather than have those same 5 columns in each of the 6 tables.

Any advice appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

That's an unnecessary set of relationships - you can get the regions/country from the city instead.

Note that I've got regions and countries the wrong way round in the image below, but it illustrates what I mean!

[image]

Naturally, it would be useful to define a view combining cities, countries and regions for actually writing your queries with. I also think that normalizing to this level is a very good idea in practice. When you come to add a new field to your locations table you will be very glad you've split it out ;-)

Comment: My only concern doing it this way is that the user can't just select a country and/or region/state. Some 'cities' < 40,000 people aren't in my database as there's 10,000+ worldwide and will slow it down to much when querying. Also the user or organisation might be in a town not a city. Then if they can't find their city in the drop-down list they won't be able to select a country or region either as it won't map back to the locations table.

Comment: How my web app currently works is a user selects a country in the drop down, it uses AJAX to show another drop-down with all the region/states in that country, then that drop-down uses AJAX again to let the user choose the cities that are in that region/state. What I'm trying to do is get these organisations searchable by country, state/region or city so when a user comes to the site they can find these organisations in the area they want. If they can't find the organisation in that city then they need to be able to search by region and it should find it then even if it's a small town.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are already overdoing it. Regions, Cities and Countries as seperate tables is great, as you have the ability to easily manage the entries without creating data inconsistence. But storing address data for each user / organisation in a seperate (locations) table is unnecessary. Add those fields to the user / organisation tables.

EDIT: RB illustrated it in much more detail :)

Comment: My problem with putting all the address, suburb, city, region, country data in each table it ends up looking like a messy spider's web: [like so](http://i.imgur.com/tfkbi.png). The problem with RB's method I addressed under his post.